# Dropdown is empty after I tried to fetch attributes out of my database with php and pg

Tags: php, jquery, database, postgresql, dropdown

I want to fetch all the column names into a dropdown menu, but the dropdown menu stays empty. But I ran the query I used directly on my database and that worked fine. This is my code:

My index script:

```
   <div class="custom_search col-md-5">
       <span>
          <select class="form-control" name="column_names" id="column_names">
            <?php              
              while ($row = pg_fetch_array($sql_column_select)) {
              echo '<option value="">'. $row['column_name'] .'</option>';
              }
            ?>
          </select>
       </span>    
    </div>
```

My php script:

```
<?php
  $sql_column_select =  ("SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='fastfood_groningen'"); 
?>
```

UPDATED php script:

```
$host = '';
$port = '';
$dbname = '';
$user = '';
$password = '';

//Make connection with database
$conn = pg_connect("host=$host port=$port dbname=$dbname user=$user password=$password");
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Not connected : " . pg_error();
    exit;
}

    $sql_column_select =  pg_query($conn, "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='fastfood_groningen'"); 
    if (!$sql_column_select) {
      echo "An error occurred.\n";
      exit;
    }
```

Still no output in my dropdown menu...

Comment: Check the quotes properly !!

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP Statement needs a closing While bracket, and you don't need the double Quotes outside the single quotes around the $row.

Corrected code:

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($sql_column_select)) {
         echo '<option value="">'. $row['column_name'] .'</option>';
}
```

**EDIT**

You aren't actually querying the database.

```
 $sql_column_select =  ("SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='fastfood_groningen'");
```

Needs to be something like:

```
$sql_column_select =  pg_exec($ConnectionString, "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='fastfood_groningen'");
```

Where your $ConnectionString is something like:

```
$ConnectionString = "host=sheep port=5432 dbname=test user=lamb password=bar";
```

Refer to this, in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-array.php)

Comment: I added the bracket but it didn't fix my problem.

Comment: Correct the quotes? And update your original post with the code you tried and it didn't work

Comment: Tryed you'r solution but it didn't work. So i searched for a solution with pg_query to execute the query but still nothing...

Comment: How are you passing the data from your php script to the index? It won't be able to see $sql_column_select unless you're either on the same page where it is declared, or you're passing to the index, if you are passing it, how are you?

Comment: Oww that's the problem i guess. I'm not passing it to my index.html file. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Simply move your code to tags at the top of your html page, or add an Include at the top of your Index.php, so something like

     require_once("phpscript.php"); that will only work if your connection to the database is actually inside the php script, so keep your string outside index.php and call it using require.